# Android emulator memory exceeds the limit when using the swiftshader_indirect gpu

Tags: android-emulator, qemu, swiftshader

I allocated 4G of memory to the virtual machine. After using browser for a period of time, QEMU
Occupies 8G memory.

```
$ cat /proc/`pidof qemu-system-x86_64`/status | egrep "VmRSS|VmHWM|VmSize|VmPeak" | awk "{print \$1 \"\t\t\" \$2/1024 \" MB\"}"
VmPeak:         15521.3 MB
VmSize:         11935.1 MB
VmHWM:          8710.93 MB
VmRSS:          8681.04 MB
```

Android emulator version: 34.1.18.0
Android version: 13
ABI: x86_64
HOST OS: Ubuntu 22.04
Create avd:

```
$ avdmanager create avd -n test-13 -k "system-images;android-34;default;x86_64" -d "Galaxy Nexus"
```

Run avd:

```
$ ./emulator/emulator -avd test-13 -debug init,memory -skip-adb-auth -no-snapshot -cores 4 -writable-system -partition-size 8192 -gpu swiftshader_indirect -qemu -cpu host  -enable-kvm -m 4096
```

QEMU occupies normal memory